# error: Tried to create relationships between tasks that don't have DAGs yet. Set the DAG for at least one task and try again

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

while we are trying to pass dag conf variables as parameters and running in a loop with decorator we are getting below error. is there a way to fix

error in **taskinfo >> completed **

```py
with DAG(
  dag_id="test_dag",
  start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 24),
  schedule_interval=None,
  render_template_as_native_obj=True,
  default_args={},
  params={
    "param2": "arya2@gmail.com",
    "sourcedir": ['/home/arya/'],
    "timenum": 0
  },
  catchup=False
) as dag:

    @task
    def make_list(lst):
        context = get_current_context()
        srcdir = []
        for number in range(0, len(lst)):
            srcdir.append(("abc" + lst[number] + "xyz"))
            taskinfo = EmptyOperator(task_id=f"taskinfo_{number}")
            taskinfo.execute(context)

            completed = f"completed{number+1}"
            completed = DummyOperator(task_id=completed,trigger_rule='all_success')

            taskinfo >> completed

    make_list("{{ params.sourcedir }}")
```

> Error: Tried to create relationships between tasks that don't have DAGs yet. Set the DAG for at least one task and try again**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task decorator allows users to convert a Python function into a task instance from `PythonOperator`. So first problem is using `@task` for your tasks generator method.

Second problem is that this method doesn't know anything about your dag, so you create 2 * len(lst) tasks which do not belong to any dag, and when you try to create the relationship between the tasks `taskinfo` and `completed`, you get this error.

Here is a simple solution:

```py
from airflow.models.param import Param

with DAG(
        dag_id="test_dag",
        start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 24),
        schedule_interval=None,
        render_template_as_native_obj=True,
        default_args={},
        params={
            "param2": "arya2@gmail.com",
            "sourcedir": ['/home/arya/'],
            "timenum": 0,
            "number_param": Param(default=1, type="number"),
            "str_param": Param(default="1", type="string"),
        },
        catchup=False
) as dag:

    def make_list(lst, dag_instance):
        context = get_current_context()
        srcdir = []
        for number in range(0, len(lst)):
            srcdir.append(("abc" + lst[number] + "xyz"))
            taskinfo = EmptyOperator(task_id=f"taskinfo_{number}", dag=dag_instance)
            taskinfo.execute(context)

            completed = f"completed{number+1}"
            completed = DummyOperator(task_id=completed,trigger_rule='all_success', dag=dag_instance)

            taskinfo >> completed

    make_list("{{ params.sourcedir }}", dag_instance=dag)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply : I am getting error : """" got an unexpected keyword argument 'dag' """"

Comment: Any suggestion pls ..

Comment: I had a mistake, I updated my answer

Comment: Hi Hussein , Need one suggestion. While reading the variables through params using "{{ params.*****}}" if the variables have alphanumeric like "0x123ABCh" the values are being converted into numerics. Is there any way to read those values as it is

Comment: I just updated my answer by providing an example of how to type your params using the class `Param`, I think this is what are you looking for

Comment: this answer does not work. You cant call `get_current_context` from outside a task

Answer (score 0):

The error went away in a three page reload. Maybe it was caused by wrong task indentation.